# How do i search an array for a value in a loop and ends with -1?

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Define original and diff as two integer arrays that could store 10 numbers each. Initialize a third integer array called newArray also for size 10 with any ten positive numbers.

Write code that prompts the user for a number and then searches newArray for that number. If the number is found: displays a message with the index of the number. If not found a suitable message is displayed. This is repeated until the user enters -1.

How do I end the loop with -1

```
 // Define Arrays

 int[] original = new int[9];

 int[] diff = new int[9];

 int[] newArray = new int[9];
```

Comment: This is homework, what have you tried? Also, what language?

Comment: Where is the code that prompts the user for anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a loop that prompts the user for input, and keeps doing so until they input -1.

```
int user_input;

while(user_input != -1)
{
    //Prompt user and get input

    //Do comparison and show result.
    for(int i = 0; i < newArray.count; i++)
    {
        if(newArray[i] == user_input)
        {
            Console.Write("Found at index " + i.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I Can't Get it To search the array and Print the index

Comment: I have modified my answer, not sure which language you're using but this should give you an idea.

Comment: Paul, May i get an email for assistance?

Comment: It's in my profile, glad I could help. Also, if my answer was helpful, you can upvote it or accept it as an answer by clicking the checkmark (or both).

Comment: email not there, it seem to be working except it prints "number not found" for every index, its jAVA and im using netbeans

Comment: How to i print elements in an array in brackets separated by commas